# How to add a package from "master" branch on meteor 0.9

Tags: meteor

In Meteor before version 0.9 you could specify the branch for a package in the smart.json file. Howerver, in Meteor 0.9 it seems that smart.json is not used at all.

Is there a way to download a specific branch of package in Meteor 0.9 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible right now since Meteor package system is not based on Git. There's an easy workaround, though, as local packages still have precedence over loaded ones.

- Checkout the package Git repository to a folder next to your project one (or in any close relative location).
- Checkout the desired branch / commit.
- Create a symlink to that repo from your project's `/packages` directory. The link must have the same name as the package, that is `prefix:packagename`.
- Add `prefix:packagename` to `/packages/.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thanks Hubert OG, but the package has dependencies and it seems it is trying to find it in that symlinked folder but it can not find it. it is throwing this error now:

Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project:
Error: unknown package: iron-router

Comment: Ahhh, never mind, fixed it, had to change iron-router to iron:router

Comment: I also had to add `prefix:pacakgename` to `.meteor/packages`, and also add it to the `smart.json` so that running `mrt` would automatically clone my desired version for me. Then it seemed to use those in the local `packages/`. I think I needed to add an explicit `name` in the `package.js`, but not sure.